# Implement an "xprevious" in LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx, algorithm, game-maker, roguelikes

I have used Gamemaker Studio 2 before, briefly, and found that the `xprevious` and `yprevious` variables are extremely useful.

Since I am developing a pixel-based roguelike in LibGDX, what is the best way to implement this? I was using this logic:

1. Create two variables, `x, xprev`
2. In the render loop (or in the player class) make `xprev` equal to `x`
3. change `x` by player speed
4. Repeat 2 & 3

However, this seems to be very glitchy. Here is my render function:

```
player.xprevious = player.position.x;
player.yprevious = player.position.y;

if(movingRight) player.position.x += speed
if(movingLeft) player.position.x -= speed;
if(movingUp) player.position.y += speed;
if(movingDown) player.position.y -= speed;
```

Since after this code the position is not being changed until the next iteration, `player.position.x` and `player.xprevious` should be different?

Right after this, I logged the values of the variables, e.g.:

`xprev 716.0, x 716.0   yprev 1435.0, y 1435.0`

Help is greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Can you describe the precise glitches you're observing? And show us the particular order in which you do these actions in your game loop?

Comment: I added some code to elaborate. Hope this helps.

Comment: If I may ask, why are you setting `xprevious = x`? I cannot expect them to be different because you're making them equall. But the code automatically sets xprevious to the 'previous x' since the last frame. If the position hasn't changed, then the previous x will stay equall to the current x.

Comment: Looking at the code as it is, there must be something either changing xprevious, or position.x isn't being changed.